# Remove all but one specific cookie from a reverse proxy request

Tags: apache, cookies, proxy

I'm using Apache 2.4.4 on a Windows machine acting as a front end to another OLD bespoke web serving application.

Lately I've been having problems with cookies being passed to the old web app, causing that web app to fail. I think this might be related to google analytics cookies but am not 100% sure.

Is it possible with Apache to remove all but one cookie from the request sent to the reverse proxy web app?

The name of the cookie which I do want to allow through is called "PM2".

Here is my reverse proxy configuration:

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>

 <ifModule mod_rewrite.c>


    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^/(.*\.[aA]4[dD])$ http://127.0.0.1:8080/$1 [P,L]

    RewriteRule ^/4DCGI/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1/$1 [P,L,nocase]      

    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080

    ProxyRequests Off

    ProxyTimeout 1200

 </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?